# xpath: how to select first <a> element from every <li> element?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

With Selenium i'm trying to select the first <a> element with a particular class from every <li> element with a particular class

this would be a representation of the HTML i'm looking at:

```
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="foo">
        <article>
          <div>
            <a class="bar 1"></a>
            <div>
              <a class="bar"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>     
      <li>
        <article>
          <div>
            <a class="bar"></a>
            <div>
              <a class="bar"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>       
      <li class="foo">
        <article>
          <div>
            <a class="bar 2"></a>
            <div>
              <a class="bar"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

So i'm looking to extract the first a element with class "bar" from every li with class "foo". so in this example i'm trying to find "bar 1" and "bar 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `//li[@class = 'foo']/descendant::a[@class = 'bar'][1]`.